# Jest - How to mock a function inside available function

Tags: node.js, api, request, jestjs

I have functions in a file as below:

```
import logger from 'logger-module';
import spir from '../spir';

const spirA = new spir(
  process.env.USERNAME,
  process.env.PASSWORD,
  process.env.API_KEY,
  process.env.SMS_WORKSPACE_ID,
  process.env.SMS_TEMPLATE_ID
);

const spirSMS = params => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    spirA.sms(params).then(resolve, reject);
  });
};

export const send = params => {
  logger.info('Sending new sms...');
  const { to: recipients, invalidNumber } = params;
  const promises = recipients.map(number =>
   spirSMS({ to: number, subject: params.subject, body: params.body })
  );
  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    logger.info(`SMS has been sent to ${recipients.toString()}!`);
    return {
      message: `SMS has been sent to ${recipients.toString()}`,
      data: {
        recipients,
        invalid_recipients: invalidNumber
      }
    };
  });
};
```

How to I can mock **spirSMS** inside **recipients.map**

I found it to be a loop function so I'm not sure how to mock it.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use Classes here for better testability of your code. somethink like this

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor(spirSms) {
    this.spirSms_ = spirSms;
  }

  send(params) {
    logger.info('Sending new sms...');
    const { to: recipients, invalidNumber } = params;
    const promises = recipients.map(number =>
     this.spirSms_({ to: number, subject: params.subject, body: params.body })
    );
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
      logger.info(`SMS has been sent to ${recipients.toString()}!`);
      return {
        message: `SMS has been sent to ${recipients.toString()}`,
        data: {
          recipients,
          invalid_recipients: invalidNumber
        }
      };
    });
  }
}

module.exports = SomeClass;
```

and then you will have some `main.js` which will instantiate your class and inject `spirSms`

```
const spirA = new spir(
  process.env.USERNAME,
  process.env.PASSWORD,
  process.env.API_KEY,
  process.env.SMS_WORKSPACE_ID,
  process.env.SMS_TEMPLATE_ID
);

const spirSMS = params => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    spirA.sms(params).then(resolve, reject);
  });
};

const someClass = new SomeClass(spirSMS);
someClass.send(params);
```

Now in your test when you will test `SomeClass`, you can inject any mock `spirSms` which will basically do what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.
Unfortunately, I can not modify code same you suggested because It is wrote by others -_-
And if I have the right to fix, it will also affect other services in the system
It will take a lot of time and effort

Comment: In that case you can use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require` which can mock a full file which is required in your main file.

Comment: Thank bro, the client doesn't allow external libraries.